# Hamiltonian Group action with infinitely many stabiliser types

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, sg.symplectic-geometry, differential-topology, group-actions

What is an example of a connected symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$, with a Hamiltonian action of $G = U(1) =S^{1}$ with infinitely many stabiliser types?

Infinitely many stabiliser types means that infinitely many sub-groups of $G$ appear as stabilisers as points in $M$.

I am aware that $M$ is necessarily non-compact.

Comment: Could you define "stabilizer type"?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will clarify in the question, maybe there is a more standard terminology for this?

Comment: I guess it's standard as I found it on Google but it didn't come with a definition (as it's natural to guess it). Here in an abelian group it can be restated as "infinitely many distincts point stabilizers". For non-abelian group actions, probably it means infinitely many up to conjugation.

Comment: You want $M$ to be connected as well I presume. Otherwise you can take a disjoint copy of $\mathbb{CP^1}$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$. The action on this sphere will be the $n$-fold rotation over this sphere.

Comment: I guess such an example arises in (real) dimension four. I don't know much about this stuff, but I think there is a delzant type theorem for non-compact toric manifolds. Then you can find a fan in the upper right quadrant in $\mathbb{R}^2$, with vertices something like $(0,0) , (1,1), (3,2), (6,3),\ldots$. Then taking the induced $S^1$ action corresponding to the vector $(0,1)$ should satisfy this condition. But I am someone more knowledgable will chime in.

Comment: Hmm, googling made me believe that this is a bit more complex than I thought. See this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0907.2891.pdf . However, I was thinking of a toric manifold with moment map similar to figure 1 in this paper.

Comment: Thank you, Yes it does seem there is a Delzant construction for open manifolds there, but after 10 minutes of reading I couldn't extract the statement about the stabilisers.

Comment: Actually now I think about it, the problem can be solved in dimension 4, by gluing together infinitely many Hamiltonian $4$-manifolds via symplectomorphic reduces spaces (with level sets with the same Seifert structure). However, I will leave the question up to see if there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: The question really has nothing to do with symplectic geometry:  Given *any* connected $n$-manifold $N^n$ with a smooth $S^1$-action with infinitely many stabilizer types, then the canonical extension of this action to $T^*N$ will be an example of a Hamiltonian $S^1$-action with infinitely many stabilizer types.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @RobertBryant it gets a little to do with symplectic geometry if you wonder about the minimal dimension of a symplectic manifold with such an action, for example.

Comment: The lowest dimension is 4, I can give argument if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an simple example with infinitely many different stabilizer subgroups you may take countably many disks. Since each disk may be rotated independently with a different speed, we obtain an action of $ U(1) $ such that all the subgroups $ \mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z$ with $ n \in \mathbb N $ occur as stabilizer.

Of course the example obtained in this way is disconnected and even has infinitely many connected components. However, one can use the same strategy to obtain a connected manifold with infinitely many distinct stabilizer groups. The idea is to embed the collection of disks in a bigger space and "smear" the action between them. Details can be found in an old paper ["On a problem of Montgomery" by C.T. Yang](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2033722).